# Azure Virtual Network Gateway - OpenVPN Private DNS resolution

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, openvpn

I have a Virtual Network Gateway set up using OpenVPN with certificate-based authentication.

I am able to connect to the OpenVPN server on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine, and while connected I am able to reach private IP addresses that are part of the network.

DNS resolution is not working, however.

If I try to ping a certain `<dbname>.postgres.database.azure.com`, it says "Name or service not known". Whereas if I pinged that hostname in one of the VMs that's part of the same Virtual Network, the private IP gets resolved.

How do I get DNS resolution to work?

Comment: Voted to migrate to [su], that's not a programming problem. But the short (and hopefully least effort) answer is: make OpenVPN hand out the internal DNS server with its DHCP lease.